# Assistance on a Particular Nested IF Excel Formula

Tags: excel, formulas, nested-if

Here's a quick summary of what I am trying to do:

I'm trying to set up an Excel workbook that will allow users to paste the results of a SQL query into a **RawData** worksheet and have multiple other worksheets then grab that data and display it in various formats (graphs, charts, etc.).

This particular formula that I'm trying to write is supposed to look at a certain column in **RawData**, compare the number listed there to a "key" in the **Key** worksheet, and then return the text equivalent to the ID displayed in RawData in a new worksheet called **StylizedData**

For example, if **RawData** lists 1, then **StylizedData** will list "Configuration" because 1 is associated with "Configuration" in the **Key**.

Here is the formula:

```
=IF(RawData!F60=Key!$C$2,Key!$D$2,
  IF(RawData!F60=Key!$C$3,Key!$D$3,
   IF(RawData!F60=Key!$C$4,Key!$D$4,
    IF(RawData!F60=Key!$C$5,Key!$D$5,
     IF(RawData!F60=Key!$C$6,Key!$D$6,
      IF(RawData!F60=Key!$C$7,Key!$D$7,
       IF(RawData!F60=Key!$C$8,Key!$D$8,
        IF(RawData!F60=Key!$C$9,Key!$D$9,
         IF(RawData!F60=Key!$C$10,Key!$D$10,
          IF(RawData!F60=Key!$C$11,Key!$D$11,
           IF(RawData!F60=Key!$C$12,Key!$D$12,
            IF(RawData!F60=Key!$C$13,Key!$D$13,
             IF(RawData!F60=Key!$C$14,Key!$D$14,
              IF(RawData!F60=Key!$C$15,Key!$D$15,
               IF(RawData!F60=Key!$C$16,Key!$D$16,
                IF(RawData!F60=Key!$C$17,Key!$D$17,
                 IF(RawData!F60=Key!$C$18,Key!$D$18,
                  IF(RawData!F60=Key!$C$19,Key!$D$19,
                   IF(RawData!F60=Key!$C$20,Key!$D$20,
                    IF(RawData!F60="",""))))))))))))))))))))
```

That whole process is working correctly all the way up until I get to the point where a row in **RawData** is empty. When the row is empty, it is displaying "No Subcategory", which is the text equivalent of **Key!$C$2** and is contained in **Key!$D$2**. I'm wanting it to display nothing, which I'm trying to accomplish with that last snippet (**IF(RawData!F60="","")**).

Can anyone help me out here?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`=if(iserror(vlookup(RawData!F60,KeyArray,2,0)),"",vlookup(RawData!F60,KeyArray,2,0)`

If the lookup value isn't found the cell gets a "" value. Otherwise it will search for the value contained in `F60` in your key array and return the value two cells to the right.

With `Vlookup()` your array/range must have the values you are searching for in the first column. Your column/array must also include the column of values you want to return. For instance you would probably use something like `$C$2:$D$20` for your key array. It also helps if your key values in your key array are sorted.

Good luck!

Comment: Thank you! That worked like a charm and was SO MUCH CLEANER than my previous formula.

Comment: Actually, strike that. It worked like a charm for all except a single column for some reason. It is again displaying "No Subcategory", which is the first item in the second column of my key array. I'm guessing this has something to do with the fact that the rows in both places are completely empty.

Here's the formula I'm using: =IF(ISERROR(VLOOKUP(RawData!F60,Key!$C$1:$D$16,2,FALSE)),"",VLOOKUP(RawData!F60,Key!$C$1:$D$16,2,FALSE))

Comment: I figured it out. One of the IDs I was using was 0. I'd like to figure out a workaround for this if possible as I'd like the system to intelligently distinguish between rows containing actual 0s and columns that are "blank".

Answer (score 2):

Try,

```
=iferror(vlookup(RawData!F60, Key!$C$2:$D$20, 2, false), text(,))
```

Comment: When I use that, I get the same result: "No Subcategory".

Comment: Then you are **not** looking up blank cells. You are looking up zero-length strings. You cannot use VLOOKUP to lookup a truly blank cell; it returns `#N/A`. You **can** however, use it to lookup a zero-length string; e.g. `""` or `TEXT(,)`.